# Keep an object up-to-date in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have around 300K objects representing the same number of rows on a table. Since loading this amount of data takes a while. I need to keep these objects on RAM. And I was wondering if Hibernate has a way to automatically keep these objects updated on RAM once they are changed on database?

Is there anyway to do this?

In [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html),

```
Persistent - a persistent instance has a representation in the database and an `identifier value. It might just have been saved or loaded, however, it is by definition in the scope of a Session. Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the database when the unit of work completes. Developers do not execute manual UPDATE statements, or DELETE statements when an object should be made transient.`
```

Does this mean that if another client changed this object on the database, would that be reflected on my objects on RAM as long as the session isn't closed?

Comment: @multiplayer1080 yes

Comment: I'm interested in that question too. I've been reading about it and i found that there is a common way to maintain the RAM updated: Using the "refresh" method inside a ScheduledExecutorService.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **Dirty check**  of Hibernate engine will take of this functionality.Any ORM engine needs a way to keep an entity updated.

Comment: What do you mean by dirty check?

Comment: Check this http://java-success.blogspot.in/2013/01/hibernate-automatic-dirty-checking-of.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't be reflected, if you mean the `Session`, as this as unit of work and normally is short lived.
You can use the Second Level Cache, there are different types of Providers that support some mechanisms for removing stale objects and getting a new version from the DB.

When you load an Entity from the DB in a Session (Get), hibernate caches it in the First Level Cache, if you request the same id later in the same sessions, you get a reference to the same object (no DB call no check if has changed).